# Generate remote XML, and consume from web page, using javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, json

I am looking at a scenario where I want to "consume" an xml/json document and build some visual elements from said date.

Per example, List of bookings for a time period. Lets say data will contain

```
<unit>
<booked>
<pic>
<booked range>
```

What I am not sure of, is how to go from accessing a query string, to catching the returned xml. This seems simple, but I cant seem get get my head around accessing the XML returned, from Javascript.

More info:

I am building a mobile app, that will display data, retrieved from XML. (I want to run the url/query string from the app, to generate a custom xml doc, and read XML data returned (not display the web page)

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Synopsis**

- Collect the xml through an ajax call.
- Xml response available as dom tree (parsed) or in lexical representation (text)
- Have the callback handler process your xml and interact with the dom
- options to process your xml:

  - XPath
  - Xslt
  - DOM functions
  - string manipulation
  - string parsing ( probably pointless, unless you have special requirements on parsing )

**Code**

A pure Javscript solution using the XMLHttpRequest ( docs: eg. [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest), [MDN usage hints](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest); there also exists a [tutorial on html5rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/) ) might look similar to the following fragment:

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

function eh_onload ( ) {
    var xmlhttp = this;
    if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4) {
        console.log ( "xmlhttp.status = " + xmlhttp.status);
        if (xmlhttp.status === 200) {
            //
            // process your xml here.
            //
            console.log ( "responseText = '" + xmlhttp.responseText + "'");
            console.log ( "xml root element  = '" + xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement.nodeName + "'");
        }
        else {
            console.log('error');
        }
    }
}

oReq.onload = eh_onload;
oReq.open("get", "http://wsearch.nlm.nih.gov/ws/query?db=digitalCollections&term=cholera", true);
oReq.send();
```

The code snippet performs an ajax request and registers a callback that will be executed upon completion of the request. As you can see, you may either access the lexical representation of the xml data received or a parsed DOM structure.

***Alternative***

In case using the [jquery](http://www.jquery.com) library is acceptable to you, you may proceed along the lines of the following code sample:

```
function eh_xml ( parsedxml, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
    // process your xml here.
    //
    console.log ( "typeof(parsedxml) = '" + typeof(parsedxml)+ "'");
    console.log ( "$('term', parsedxml).length = " + $("term", parsedxml).length);
}

$.ajax({
      url: "http://wsearch.nlm.nih.gov/ws/query?db=digitalCollections&term=cholera"
    , dataType: "xml"
    , success: eh_xml
});
```

The code snippet performs an ajax request and provides a callback that receives the xml in parsed (DOM) representation.

**Note & Caveat**

The code sample uses a public web service provided by the US NIH returning xml data. This one has been selected randomly and is employed **for the sole purpose to have a working PoC**. No  affiliations exist and the usual legal disclaimers apply.

The code can be tested from the console (eg. in Chrome) opened on the  site http://wsearch.nlm.nih.gov/ using the following prelude which loads the jquery library in the context of the site hosting the web service:

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js";
script.type = "text/javascript";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
```